# Нужно ли склонять ПАОК и ХИК?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, аббревиатуры

Вопрос из мира спорта. Есть названия иностранных клубов типа ПАОК, ХИК. Нужно ли их склонять (с ПАОКом, у ХИКа)?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Comment: @Сибиряк тема не праздная, ПСЖ сделано по другой модели, это скорее обозначение, чем сокращение: Paris Saint-Germain F.C. И еще одно, аббревиатуры разных типов (читаемые по слогам и по названиям букв) проявляют разую тенденцию к склонению. ПСЖ - это как раз второго типа, читаемое по названиям букв. Потому и не склоняется ни при каких обстоятельствах.

Answer (score 1):

> «Словарь грамматических вариантов русского языка» Л. К. Граудиной, В.
> А. Ицковича и Л. П. Катлинской (М., 2008) рекомендует склонять
> аббревиатуры ВАК, ГОСТ, МХАТ, ВГИК, ТЮЗ, СПИД, ОМОН. Прочие
> аббревиатуры в строгой деловой письменной речи **не склоняются**. В
> разговорной речи склонение возможно: пробка на МКАДе, сотрудник ЗАГСа.
> [*(Источник.)*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/60-rubric-91)

Таким образом, аббревиатуры ПАОК и ХИК не стоит склонять в строгой речи, однако в спонтанной речи это вполне возможно.

Answer (score -3):

Я против склонения таких названий. Я не помню случая, когда бы иноязычная аббревиатура (по крайней мере не перешедшая в разряд заимствований, т.е. записываемая заглавными буквами) склонялась. 
Тут же очень простая мысль. У такой аббревиатуры невозможно корректно определить грамматический род - а значит и правила склонения.

Кстати, из списка Граудиной-Ицковича. ВАК там предлагается склонять по мужской парадигме. Это само по себе вызывает вопросы. Объяснение тому есть, но оно настолько неочевидно, что переносить его на всякие "паоки" и "хики" не очень-то и получится. Есть другое хорошее правило (в том же источнике), которое по-простому может звучать так. Коли уж начал склонять, то пиши строчными, Лопатин, если не ошибаюсь, тоже такой позиции придерживается. Ну так вот ни ПАОК, ни ХИК, ни тем более упомянутый в комментарии ПСЖ строчными ну никак не запишешь.

Так что в целом я против склонений, даже со скидкой на разговорный стиль.

Comment: Лопатин не предлагал писать МИД строчными буквами, но очевидно, что аббревиатура склоняется (это факт, а не рекомендация).

Comment: @Aer про МИД не могу сказать, там у него ***общая*** рекомендация. А факт вообще не из той оперы. Я много таких "фактов", только какое это все отношение к вопросу имеет?!